# select data from one table depending smilarity of other table

Tags: mysql

I have two table those are

```
 marks( pk,sub_id,std_id,mark,yar,term )
```

and

```
 six(pk,std_id,roll,yar)
```

Now I want to select the distinct marks from marks table which std_id match to six table's std_id, and match the yar and term on marks table in some selected data.

I have write this query

```
$query="SELECT distinct marks.std_id from marks inner join $cls 
on marks.std_id=$cls.std_id 
where marks.yar='$yar' and marks.term='$term' order by marks.std_id asc";
```

but it ok in my local server  but it is problem in hosting.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
$query="
    SELECT DISTINCT m.std_id FROM marks as m
      INNER JOIN ".$cls." ON marks.std_id=".$cls.std_id." 
      WHERE m.yar='".$yar."' AND m.term='".$term."' 
      ORDER BY m.std_id ASC";
```

Comment: Is it possible to change this query as------->
 
"SELECT DISTINCT m.std_id FROM marks as m 
      INNER JOIN ".$cls." ON marks.std_id=".$cls.std_id." and marks.yar=".$cls.yar 
      WHERE m.yar='".$yar."' AND m.term='".$term."' 
      ORDER BY m.std_id ASC";

Comment: Last problem is not sovled, yet.May be very rough problem !